# Incorrect display of data on the screen while performing filter in Recycle View

Tags: java, android, filter, android-recyclerview

### Discription:

I have an android app, and in one of parts of it user can choose his skills, like tags in https://stackoverflow.com

[image]

So when user taps on plus button, he can see all available skills and choose 
what he wants 
[image]

As you see there is a filter in the top of the screen, to find skills that user wants to add. And here comes the problem, and it has many impacts

For example if i type "Eng" to find "English", the result will be "Spanish"
[image]

Do not hurry to tell me, that the problem is in filtring algorithm, because
my console logs, say, that result is correct, and filter find only "English"
What is more if i choose this option, the correct answer "English" is displayed under the "Spanish"
[image]

What is more is if a i save changes, in my account is shown that i actually choose "English"
[image: You can see the difference between fist screenshoot and this]

So filtring is correct, and saving data is correct to, the problem is in displaying skills names. Why i call it magic? because console logs right before displaying the result show correct name

And i noticed that if i will go back to full list of skills it will be wrong displayed too

[image]

But as in previous cases, my console logs says, that all is OK, and i have normal skill list without duplicates

Here is my code samples :

search - is simple EditText field

```
search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            chipAdapter.getFilter().filter(charSequence);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```

Adapter :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ChipAdapterAllSkills.ChipViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    String skill = filtredSkillList.get(position).getName();
    System.err.println("SKILL "+skill+" position "+position);
    holder.skillChip.setChipText(skill);
    holder.skillChip.setSelectable(true);
    holder.skillChip.setSelected(true);
    holder.skillChip.setTextColor(MainAplication.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.accent));
    holder.skillChip.changeBackgroundColor(MainAplication.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
    holder.skillChip.setOnSelectClickListener(new OnSelectClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectClick(View v, boolean selected) {

            System.err.println(selected);
            if(!selected) {
                SelectSkills.getSkillsToAdd().add(filtredSkillList.get(position));
            }else {
                SelectSkills.getSkillsToAdd().remove(filtredSkillList.get(position));
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return  filtredSkillList.size();
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {

            String target = charSequence.toString();
            if (target.isEmpty()) {
                filtredSkillList = skillList;
            } else {
                List<Skill> list = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Skill s : skillList) {
                    if (s.getName().toLowerCase().contains(target.toLowerCase())) {
                        list.add(s);
                        System.err.println(s.getName());
                    }
                }
                filtredSkillList = list;
            }
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = filtredSkillList;
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            filtredSkillList = (ArrayList<Skill>) filterResults.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    };
}
```

I really don`t know what is going on, maybe some of you can help)

I have suspicions that maybe problem is in threading, but i didn`t do any changes in them in this piece of code

Comment: @pskink to be honest  - No )

Comment: @pskink i will try, but why do you think this is a solve to my problem?

Comment: try to clear() list

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not in my code.
There is some Issues in Library that i`m using to create skill -chips.

Because with other libraries all works fine)